# Source of unusual synonym for Sundog

Tags: synonyms

The most common usage for Sundog is a mock sun or [parhelion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_dogs).

I also find ongoing references to a Sundog as "A nomad, without strong group affiliation and the permanent residency it affords" in Bruce Sterling's [Schismatrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schismatrix#Vocabulary) and Brian Ball's [Sundog](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/b/brian-n-ball/sundog.htm).

It's not unheard of for authors to make up or re purpose words but I find it odd to see two or more identical usages.

Is there another source for this synonym that I have not found or is this just chance?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the meaning of [Sundog](http://www.aamboli.com/translate/sundog) is

> a bright spot on the parhelic circle; caused by diffraction by ice
>   crystals

with synonyms as **mock sun** and **parhelion**.

The meaning and synonyms that you referred to in the Science Fiction works is probably a one-off thing. Possibly Ball brought it in first with his 1965 work SunBall and Bruce Sterling picked it up for his work Schismatrix.

However in the early 80s there was a science fiction video game on a similar theme [Sun Dog: Frozen Legacy](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/sundog_frozen_legacy). Interestingly this came out before Sterling's novel.

But in all likelihood this was a term that Ball used in his pretty famous novel, and which just went on.

In fact Stephen King also brought in a novel with the title **Four Past Midnight: The Sun Dog** wherein the "Sun Dog" is simply a monster dog. :-)

Comment: This does not answer the question other than to say 'probably not'.